# How do I create single audio file of video calls? Having both participants audio in single file?

Tags: twilio, audio-streaming, composition, videocall, amazon-transcribe

We are using twilio video call. We need to create real time transcription for this call. How shall I do that? We tried to use twilio composition api but it's taking too long.

Tried twilio composition api to compose the separate audio files from each participant.  This takes forever to create the composition. We need it near real time.

Comment: Exactly my problem. Compositions are really slow.